# Make other block disappear when chose a value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How can I make other filter button disappear when picked 1 value.

Here is my code base:

```
const FilterBlock = props => {
    const {
        filterApi,
        filterState,
        filterFrontendInput,
        group,
        items,
        name,
        onApply,
        initialOpen
    } = props;

    const { formatMessage } = useIntl();
    const talonProps = useFilterBlock({
        filterState,
        items,
        initialOpen
    });
    const { handleClick, isExpanded } = talonProps;
    const classStyle = useStyle(defaultClasses, props.classes);
    const ref = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleClickOutside = event => {
            if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
                isExpanded && handleClick();
            }
        };
        document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, true);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, true);
        };
    }, [isExpanded]);

    const list = isExpanded ? (
        <Form>
            <FilterList
                filterApi={filterApi}
                filterState={filterState}
                name={name}
                filterFrontendInput={filterFrontendInput}
                group={group}
                items={items}
                onApply={onApply}
            />
        </Form>
    ) : null;

    return (
        <div
            data-cy="FilterBlock-root"
            aria-label={itemAriaLabel}
            ref={ref}
        >
            <Menu.Button
                data-cy="FilterBlock-triggerButton"
                type="button"
                onClick={handleClick}
                aria-label={toggleItemOptionsAriaLabel}
            >
                <div>
                    <span>
                        {name}
                    </span>
                    <svg
                        width="8"
                        height="5"
                        viewBox="0 0 8 5"
                        fill="none"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    >
                        <path
                            d="M6.97291 0.193232C7.20854"
                            fill="currentColor"
                        />
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </Menu.Button>
            <div>
                <div>
                    {list}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

I am trying to achieve when I chose 1 value inside filter block the other block will disappear. Anyone have idea how can I work on this?

I am using React and Redux for this project

Thank you for helping me on this!!!!

[image]

Update:

Added parent component for FilterBlock.ks:

```
const FilterSidebar = props => {
    const { filters, filterCountToOpen } = props;
    const talonProps = useFilterSidebar({ filters });
    const {
        filterApi,
        filterItems,
        filterNames,
        filterFrontendInput,
        filterState,
        handleApply,
        handleReset
    } = talonProps;

    const filterRef = useRef();
    const classStyle = useStyle(defaultClasses, props.classes);

    const handleApplyFilter = useCallback(
        (...args) => {
            const filterElement = filterRef.current;
            if (
                filterElement &&
                typeof filterElement.getBoundingClientRect === 'function'
            ) {
                const filterTop = filterElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                const windowScrollY =
                    window.scrollY + filterTop - SCROLL_OFFSET;
                window.scrollTo(0, windowScrollY);
            }

            handleApply(...args);
        },
        [handleApply, filterRef]
    );

    const [selectedBlock, setSelectedBlock] = useState();

    const filtersList = useMemo(
        () =>
            Array.from(filterItems, ([group, items], iteration) => {
                const blockState = filterState.get(group);
                const groupName = filterNames.get(group);
                const frontendInput = filterFrontendInput.get(group);
                if (selectedBlock) {
                    return (
                        <FilterBlock
                            key={group}
                            filterApi={filterApi}
                            filterState={blockState}
                            filterFrontendInput={frontendInput}
                            group={group}
                            items={items}
                            name={groupName}
                            onApply={handleApplyFilter}
                            initialOpen={iteration < filterCountToOpen}
                            iteration={iteration}
                            id={selectedBlock}
                            onSelected={setSelectedBlock}
                        />
                    );
                }

                return (
                    <FilterBlock
                        key={group}
                        filterApi={filterApi}
                        filterState={blockState}
                        filterFrontendInput={frontendInput}
                        group={group}
                        items={items}
                        name={groupName}
                        onApply={handleApplyFilter}
                        initialOpen={iteration < filterCountToOpen}
                        iteration={iteration}
                        id={selectedBlock}
                        onSelected={setSelectedBlock}
                    />
                );
            }),
        [
            filterApi,
            filterItems,
            filterNames,
            filterFrontendInput,
            filterState,
            filterCountToOpen,
            handleApplyFilter
        ]
    );

    return (
        <div className="container px-4 mx-auto">
            <Menu
                as="div"
                className="my-16 justify-center flex flex-wrap py-5 border-y border-black border-opacity-5"
            >
                {filtersList}
            </Menu>
        </div>
    );
};
```

`console.log(filterItems)` and it gave me this output:

> Map(3) {'markforged_printer_type' => Array(3),
> 'markforged_material_filter' => Array(7), 'markforged_parts_filter' =>
> Array(7)} [[Entries]] 0 :  {"markforged_printer_type" => Array(3)} 1 :
> {"markforged_material_filter" => Array(7)} 2 :
> {"markforged_parts_filter" => Array(7)}

Comment: Anyone have idea how can I make this work ?

Comment: Does anyone have idea how can I make this work ?

Comment: I'm inclined to say that it should be fairly trivial to conditionally render these filter buttons/blocks based upon *some* filter state being selected. Can you clarify what exactly you are trying to do and what specifically isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated Answer

From the changes you provided, you are using `useMemo()` and `useCallback()`. Those kinds of optimizations in general are not necessary to be made or even decrease performance in some cases. Check [this article from Kent C. Dodds](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback) (others can be easily found about the theme) to explain some issues with it.

About the changes, as a suggestion, you could use the `.map()`/`.filter()` functions instead `Array.from()`.

You are splitting logic about rendering different components with the `useMemo()`, and this could be changed into one component instead of this whole logic inside the `Parent` component. (For my suggestion this will be not the case)

As a guide to your code, you could use something like this:

```
const FilterSidebar = ({ filters, filterCountToOpen }) => {
  // here you have the state to control if there is a block selected
  const [selectedGroup, setSelectedGroup] = useState();
  const {
    // only those are needed for this example
    filterItems,
    handleApplyFilter
  } = useFilterSidebar({ filters });

  return (
    <div className="container px-4 mx-auto">
      <Menu
        as="div"
        className="my-16 justify-center flex flex-wrap py-5 border-y border-black border-opacity-5"
      >
        {filterItems.map(([group, items], iteration) => {
          const groupName = filterNames.get(group);
          if (selectedGroup !== null && selectedGroup !== groupName) {
            // returning null here should not render anything for this list item
            return null;
          }

          return (
            <FilterBlock
              // pass all your extra props here
              // but the important one is the `onApply`
              onApply={(...args) => {
                setSelectedGroup((prev) => prev !== null ? null : groupName);
                return handleApplyFilter(...args);
              }}
            />
          );
        }}
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you see any `null` on your screen, you could use first the `.filter()` and then the `.map()` or combine both with a single `.reduce()`. It should be something like this:

```
        {filterItems
          .filter(([group, items]) => selectedGroup === null || selectedGroup === filterNames.get(group))
          .map(([group, items], iteration) => {
            const groupName = filterNames.get(group);
            return (
              <FilterBlock
                // pass all your extra props here
                // but the important one is the `onApply`
                onApply={(...args) => {
                  setSelectedGroup((prev) => prev !== null ? null : groupName);
                  return handleApplyFilter(...args);
                }}
              />
            );
          }}
```

With your update, it is possible to see that you can select by the `group` (instead of the `block` which it was called before). Also, you can just add a little change to your `onApply` prop and that will save and re-render the list. If the `selectedGroup` is already there, removing the filter will show the other sections. Eventually, you'll need to trim this logic to accommodate other things such as selecting more than one filter and checking for that and so on.

### Original Answer

From what you described I'm assuming what you want is: You have 3 `FilterBlock`s on your screen. Once a user selects one checkbox inside one opened "select" (that you are calling `FilterBlock`), you want the other  `FilterBlock`s disappear from the screen and just the single `FilterBlock` with the selected option to stay at the screen (the other 2 will be hidden).

If that's your case, there are some possible options to achieve that but the easiest one is controlling this on a Parent Component: You can pass a prop from the parent component named something like `onSelected`, give an `id` to each `FilterBlock`, and when one filter is selected inside, you trigger that callback with the `id` from that `FilterBlock`.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [selectedBlock, setSelectedBlock] = useState();

  if (selectedBlock) {
    return <FilterBlock id={selectedBlock} onSelected={setSelectedBlock} />
  }

  return (
    <>
      <FilterBlock id="filter-block-1" onSelected={setSelectedBlock} />
      <FilterBlock id="filter-block-2" onSelected={setSelectedBlock} />
      <FilterBlock id="filter-block-2" onSelected={setSelectedBlock} />
    </>
  )
}

const FilterBlock = ({ id, onSelected }) => (
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => onSelected(id)}>Select filter block {id}</button>
      <button onClick={() => onSelected()}>Unselect filter block {id}</button>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: I just added parent component can you take a look at my code? Thanks

Comment: Any update on the answer ?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `selectedBlock` to the dependencies array of your `useMemo()`? Also, I **hardly recommend** you avoid using `useMemo()` and `useCallback()`. Just use it if needed to improve performance. You can read more about it in [this article from Kent C. Dodds](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback) (and many others if you search for).

Comment: It worked great, I selected one checkbox it disappear 2 other filter block that is correct but when I checked another checkbox it appear 2 other filter block.

Comment: If you read the complete answer, you'll notice that phrase: "_Eventually, you'll need to trim this logic to accommodate other things such as selecting more than one filter and checking for that and so on_". You'll have to trim the logic a little to check if it has more than one filter applied but this should be easy and will depend on the implementation of the `<FilterList />` `onApply` callback and its `...args`. Check if those `...args` have some kind of `filters` value or something like that.

Comment: Yes they do when I do `console.log(...args)` it gave me this `{title: 'Industrial Composite', value: '286'}`. Any idea what can I do with these. ?

Comment: Any update on this one ?

Comment: You can use this to trim your logic. This is very dependent on the internal implementation of your components. One idea on top of my mind is to use this and check if this value exists, you can add more filters by maintaining it.